# jQuery delay on load

Tags: jquery, magento

Hi I have the piece of code which is being used to make images grey and when you hover on image they fade in to color.

I seem to have a slight issue with it as it flicks to color first then to grey before working.

Is there a way of making it load quicker? Is it a conflict that is causing this delay or is it just not good code being used.

An example of a page where it is being used is here:
http://www.emmaphillipsbridal.com/brides/gowns.html

Comment: You need to give us code to review.

Comment: This is not related to slow loading. You first load the actual image and only then you make it grayscale. Can't really see any way around except hiding each image until it's grayscaled.

Comment: +1 to Shadow Wizard. You should load the grayscale image initially, and then do your jQuery voodoo on it to load the color image when the user hovers. You may want to consider using the jQuery plugin `hoverIntent()` to prevent the colored image from loading if a user is being a spazz with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it is the function `grayscale()` that takes some time to render each of the cloned images. I would try to initially hide the images through CSS and then show them after the `clone image` loop